# Pyparsing for Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have recently installed PyParsing, but I saw that it's only available on Python 2, but I use Python 3.
I just don't want to learn Python 2, so is there a way to configure/port PyParsing to Python 3?

Comment: The most recent version of pyparsing 2.0.3 is compatible with Python 3.  Where did you see that is it only available for Python 2?

Comment: I tested to import 'pyparsing', 'PyParsing', 'pyParsing' and 'Pyparsing' and nothing worked.

Comment: pyparsing is not part of the builtin Python distribution. It is a 3rd party add-on, so you must install it using `easy_install` or `pip`.

Comment: The correct form is `import pyparsing`, or `from pyparsing import name,name,name,...` or `from pyparsing import *`

Comment: And if you installed pyparsing for your Python3 environment, you will need to install it again for Python2.

Comment: Yes, I've used `pip`, then I tried to `import pyparsing`, then `import PyParsing`, then `import Pyparsing`, but nothing worked. And yes, I've tried to install it for Python 3, but it worked only on Python 2.5

Comment: You can stop trying all the variations - the module is named `pyparsing` and you import it using `import pyparsing`.  If you are absolutely desperate, pyparsing consists of only a single Python file, `pyparsing.py`, which you can copy from your Python 2 installation to your Python3 site packages directory by hand.  Or download it from Sourceforge using this link: http://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/pyparsing.py?format=raw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to *learn* [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x). It isn't exactly *learning*, since you already know the language, you just need to familiarize yourself with the syntax, for which [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) and [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_syntax.htm) help.